# (JS) How can I get the values from the message?

Tags: javascript, telegram

I have a command like '/set 18472000 1000', where 18472000 is TG user_id, and 1000 is the amount. How can I get those values from the message to put it into variables?

Comment: Seemed pretty clear what they were asking to me

Comment: set is my own command, i wrote 'command like', and the answer wasn't about '/set' command, it was about getting values from message

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
const input = '/set 18472000 1000'

const fields = input.split(' ')

const [ , id, value ] = fields

console.log(id)

console.log(value)
```